# Acessar um Repositório Singleton fora do Controller (Injeção de Dependencia)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, injeção-de-dependência

tenho uma instancia de Repositório adicionado como Scoped no Startup e para acessar a instancia faço a injeção de dependência pelo construtor do Controller, ou pelo FromServices. Porém, preciso acessar o Repository dentro de um método pra classe, para não escrever o código no Controller e Isolar as responsabilidades da aplicação. Mas não consigo passar a instancia por parâmetro no Método, pois para chamar ele, ele pede justamente a instancia no parametro. Como posso capturar essa instancia dentro da minha Classe?

```
internal static async Task<List<WmsEstoque>> PreencheGrid([FromServices] WmsEstoqueRepository _WmsEstoqueRepository)
{
    return await _WmsEstoqueRepository.ListarIdCliente(534);
}
```

E Como chamo o método

```
var listaestoque = await WmsEstoque.PreencheGrid();
```

Mensagem de erro:

Não há nenhum argumento fornecido que corresponde ao parâmetro formal necessário "_WmsEstoqueRepository" de "WmsEstoque.PreencheGrid(WmsEstoqueRepository)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que você esteja confundindo as 2 formas e fazer injeção de dependências.

### Parâmetro no construtor

Como você mesmo citou, colocando um parâmetro no construtor é o de prata receber uma instância do repositório que você espera. Para tornar essa instância disponível para um método da classe normalmente criamos um campo na classe para guardar esse parâmetro recebido no construtor.
Essa forma de DI é possível a mais comum em aplicações ASP.net:

```cs
public class MyController : Controller // ou ApiController
{
    // campo para guardar o repositório injetado
    // usando "readonly" somente prata deixar explícito
    // que ele só será setado uma vez no construtor
    private readonly IMyRepository myRepo;

    public MyController(IMyRepository repo) 
    {
        // o construtor sempre será executado então podermos considerar
        // que myRepo sempre terá o valor esperado quando qualquer um
        // dos métodos é executado.
        this.myRepo = repo;
    }

    public List<string> GetRecords()
    {
        return this.myRepo.GetRecords().ToList();
    } 
}
```

### Parâmetro na action (*método*)

Actions, que são métodos públicos de um controller, também podem receber instâncias por DI diretamente com o atributo `[FromService]`. É importante notar que *actions* não são normalmente invocadas via código, mas sim pelo framework quando uma requisição é feita para uma URl específica. Ou seja, a responsabilidade de invocar *actions* é do framework e ele sabe como lidar com as dependências via atributos.

### Injeção de dependências fora do controller

Outra coisa que você comentou é isolar a regra de negócio do controller. A grande maioria das bibliotecas de injeção de dependência pra .Net vai automaticamente injetar as dependências (que tiverem sido registradas) para a "árvore de objetos" que forem criados.
Um exemplo simples, imagina que você quer executar algumas validações antes de adicionar um novo objeto no seu banco de dados. Você poderia fazer algo como:

```cs
public class PedidosController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IPedidoService pedidoService;
    public PedidosController(IPedidoService pedidoService)
    {
        // Se pedidoService for null, gera exceção
        this.pedidoService = pedidoService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(pedidoService));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Finalizar(PedidoDto pedidoDto)
    {
        var pedido = new Pedido { // extrai propriedades de "pedidoDto" };
        this.pedidoService.FinalizarPedido(pedido);
    }
}


public class PedidoService : IPedidoService
{
    private readonly IEstoqueRepository estoqueRepository;
    private readonly IDescontoService descontoService;
    private readonly IPedidoRepository pedidoRepository;

    // Essa classe será instanciado pelo sistema de DI com as dependências necessárias
    public PedidoService(IPedidoRepository pedidoRepository, IEstoqueRepository estoqueRepository, IDescontoService descontoService)
    {
        this.pedidoRepository = pedidoRepository ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(pedidoRepository));
        this.estoqueRepository = estoqueRepository ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(estoqueRepository));
        this.descontoService = descontoService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(descontoService));
    }

    public void FinalizarPedido(Pedido pedido)
    {
        // Aqui você pode usar uma regra de negócio mais complexa,
        // e o melhor de duto é que essa código pode ser facilmente executado de qualquer lugar, não somente de um controller.

        this.descontoService.ValidarDescontos(pedido);

        if (!this.estoqueRepositor.IsProdutoEmEstoque(pedido.ProdutoId))
        {
            // Colocar em espera ou mandar e-mail?
        }
        else
        {
            var pedidoCriado = this.pedidoRepository.CriarPedido(pedido);
            // enviar e-mail com numero do pedido
        }
    }
}
```

### Update para o seu caso específico

Baseado na discussão nos comentários, o `WsEstoque` é um serviço que deveria ser injetado no seu controller diretamente pelo sistema de injeção de dependências. Para isso você precisa registrar essa dependência junto com as outras:

```cs
// Normalmente interfaces são geradas para desacoplar consumidores da implementação de um dependência
// e também para facilitar na criação de testes unitários.
services.AddScoped<IWsEstoque, WsEstoque>();
```

É comum ter dezenas de serviços sendo registrados dessa forma. Sistemas mais complexos utilizam bibliotecas mais robustas de injeção de dependências para facilitar no processo de registrar dependências e também para gerar "módulos" separando diferente áreas do sistema de forma (exemplo: [Autofac](https://autofac.org/), [Simple Injector](https://simpleinjector.org/)).

Existe também uma biblioteca para auxiliar a registrar várias dependências de uma só vez com o sistema de DI padrão do .net core, o [NetCoreAutoRegisterDi](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NetCore.AutoRegisterDi). Com ele você pode registrar todas as classes no seu assembly/projeto com um único comando:

```cs
// Registra todas as classes públicas onde o nome começa com
// a string "Ws" para a sua respectiva interface.
service.RegisterAssemblyPublicNonGenericClasses()
     .Where(c => c.Name.StartsWith("Ws"))
     .AsPublicImplementedInterfaces();
```

Comment: IPValverde, perfeito, entendi a lógica, o problema é que tentei injetar pelo constructor da Classe, assim como método que vc fez de exemplo, mas, o .Net não entende meu contexto.. A mensagem quando faço instancio no Controller (exemplo):
var wmsestoque = new WmsEstoque, ele retorna pedindo o Repository - 
 "message": "Não há nenhum argumento fornecido que corresponde ao parâmetro formal necessário \"WmsEstoqueRepository\" de \"WmsEstoque.WmsEstoque(WmsEstoqueRepository)\"

Comment: Se o `WmsEstoque` for um serviço/repositório com dependências no construtor você não deveria estar criando uma instância dele manualmente. Você só precisa registrar ele no sistema de injeção de dependências e receber ele no construtor do seu controler já inicializado.

Comment: IPValverde o `WmsEstoque` é minha classe onde preciso fazer o método Complexo, e dentro desse método, preciso acessar o `WmsEstoqueRepository`, que é meu repositório de acesso a dados.. O que estou com dificuldade é que, mesmo passando o` WmsEstoqueRepository` que foi previamente registrado como AddScoped no Startup, e instanciando ele no Construtor do Controller onde chamo o método da Classe `WmsEstoque`, quando instancio a classe WmsEstoque, ele pede para passar a instancia do `WmsEstoqueRepository`, o que não faz sentido pra mim, a instancia deveria vir injetada pelo .Net

Comment: Ele compila apenas dessa forma:

`var wmsestoque =new WmsEstoque(this._WmsEstoqueRepository);`
`var listaestoque = await wmsestoque.PreencheGrid();`

Como estou instanciando o WmsEstoqueRepository, no Constructor do Controller, e tb no Constructor da classe, o .Net não passaria a instancia por contexto?

Comment: O seu `wsEstoque` seria o equivalente do `PedidoSdrvice` do exemplo. Você não precisa criar uma instância dele, deixe que ele seja injetado no construtor do seu Controller

Comment: Valeu IPValderde, então preciso fazer a injeção de dependência da Classe WmsEstoque no Startup tb, agora ou pra outro assunto, já que vou ter 20, 30, 40 classes nessa condição talvez, e não teria necessidade de instanciar todas como Scoped, visto que talvez o usuário pode usar apenas uma dessas... Obrigado!